# Continuity of a piecewise function involving partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The following is from *Lie Groups* by Daniel Bump.  I'm currently a bit inexperienced with differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and would appreciate some guidance through this proof.

[image]

What is meant by "convergence is uniform on compact sets in $x_2, ... , x_n$?"  And what does this have to do with Taylor's theorem?

For example, let's consider the case $n = 2$.  Taylor's theorem as stated here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) says that there exist functions $h_1, h_2$ such that

$$f(x,y) = f(0,0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)y + h_1(x,y)x + h_2(x,y)y$$

and $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} h_i(x,y) = 0$.  Here $f(0,0) = 0$, and also evidently $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}(0,0) = 0$.  How can I get the "remainder form" of Taylor's theorem as in the proof?

Moreover, what does this have to do with continuity?  We need to that for any fixed $x = (0, x_2, ... , x_n) \in U$, the limit $\lim\limits_{y \to x} g(y) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})(0,x_2, ... , x_n)$.

Comment: You can use that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth iff for every smooth function $x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x(t))$ is smooth $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Looking at $g(y) = f(x_1,y)- f(0,y)$ you'll find that $\frac{g(x(t))}{x_1(t)}$ is smooth.

Comment: This lemma seems to be stating the following 'obvious' fact: given $f$ smooth, $\int \limits_{0}^1\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}(tx,y)dt$ is also smooth. Note, for any $(x,y)$, we may define the function $g(t):=f(tx,y)$. Hence, $g(1)-g(0)=\int \limits_0^1 g'(t)dt$. Plugging in $f$ and using the chain rule, we get $f(x,y)-f(0,y)=\int \limits_{0}^1 x\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}(tx,y)dt. $ By the lemma's assumption, $f(0,y)$ is $0$, so we may write $f(x,y)=x\int \limits_{0}^1\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}(tx,y)dt$. Hence this integral is exactly the function $g$ in the Lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix $x_2,\ldots, x_n$ and consider the function of one variable $h(t)=f(t, x_2,\ldots, x_n)$, then 
$h(x_1)=h(0)+h'(0)x_1+\frac12h''(c)x_1^2$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x_1$. This means 
$$f(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)=f(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)x_1+\frac12\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(c, x_2,\ldots, x_n)x_1^2.$$ Hence
$$\frac{f(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}{x_1}=0+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)+\frac12\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(c, x_2,\ldots, x_n)x_1$$ and so
$$\left\vert\frac{f(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}{x_1}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)\right\vert\le\frac12\left\vert\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(c, x_2,\ldots, x_n)\right\vert |x_1|.$$
The problem is that $c$ depends on $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ but if you stay in a closed ball or closed rectangle in $U$ then  $\left\vert\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(c, x_2,\ldots, x_n)\right\vert\le M$ in that closed set.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now why $g$ is continuous.  Now I'm trying to understand why $\frac{\partial g }{\partial x_1}$ defined at every point at $U$, before I show that it is continuous.  For a point $(0, x_2, ... , x_n) \in U$, I need to check that the limit

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h,x_2, ... , x_n) - g(0,x_2, ... , x_n)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{h}f(h,x_2, ... , x_n) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0,x_2, ... , x_n)}{h}$$

exists, but it doesn't seem so straightforward.  Do you have any suggestions/hints?

Comment: This is also equal to 

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{h}[\frac{1}{h}f(h,x_2, ... , x_n) - \frac{1}{ \epsilon} f(\epsilon,x_2, ... , x_n)]$$

where both expressions in the parentheses  converge to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0, x_2, ... , x_n)$ separately.

Comment: Just use the same Taylor's formula $$\frac{\frac{f(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}{x_1}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}{x_n}=\frac12\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(c, x_2,\ldots, x_n)\to \frac12\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(0, x_2,\ldots, x_n)$$ as $x_1\to 0$.